# Android 9 crash in unknown class

Tags: android

I've a strange crash happening only on Android 9 devices :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at xf.b (xf.java:99)
  at xh.run (xh.java:3)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6669)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Mostly Pixel phones but not only.
Problem is that xh.java and xf.java classes are nowhere :

- not in classes.dex
- not in proguard mapping file
- no occurence in Android Studio

where does it come from ?
I can't reproduce using Android P in emulator...

Comment: Is there any piece of code which is deprecated and still you're using it ?

Comment: No... No warning when building release version :/

Comment: Okay, that's weird. One thing is for sure is that, crash is related to API 28 as you're pointing to, may be it's related to some of library code you're using.

Comment: weird as its not present in classes.dex of the apk